# Configure jenkins job to release multiple git repos

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, release, artifactory

I'm trying to setup a jenkins project to promote and release artifacts to artifactory from multiple git repos that use maven (and java) and which are in a dependency hierarchy.

Currently, we have two build projects for each repo, one handles snapshot and merge request builds, and the other is configured with the artifactory release plugin to promote and release artifacts. Our promotion process involves a person manually clicking the artifactory release staging button on each project in dependency order. This allows for human error and we've already had issues where projects weren't released and/or projects built in the incorrect oder.

I've tried setting up a MultiJob project and I've also tried multiple git SCMs in a single project configuration. Both of these are not compatible with the release plugin. Despite this seeming like a common use case, I haven't found any example configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of of the release builds being kicked manually you can actually make them dependent on a previous build by making the Job B a downstream job of the previous Job A this ways the Job B will only be run if the Job A ran successfully and will prevent room for human error.

Here is the plugin that might be helpful to doing this sort of setup:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin

Comment: I was hoping to not have to maintain 2 jenkins projects for every repo moving forward. But that may be the only option. Thanks.